# Reg:ILMerge for exe files

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to merge two exe file using ILMerge. When I execute the merged exe, it is only execuing the primary exe..Could any one tell me how an ILMerge can be used for merging the exe files

Comment: You don't really expect *two* programs to start from one file, do you?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hans ...I want to execute both of them using one exe..That is why I am trying for a Merged one

Answer (score 0):

Based on information from [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) and [here](http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2009/03/merge-multiple-exe-and-dll-into-one-single-file-in-net.html), what you want is not possible. Only one EXE can run.

For ilmerge.exe, the first file argument is treated as primary, others will be packaged as DLLs. How the primary file will work is something you can control using a command line argument `t` (you need `/t:exe`, but it will only run one file, the first one).

> The t parameter is used to set output type: exe for Console app, winexe for Windows forms, librarys for DLL.